# How to share a volatile field with another thread

Tags: java, multithreading, memory, volatile

```java
private static boolean stop = false;
private static volatile boolean stop_volatile = false;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Thread thread0 = new Thread(() -> {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        stop = true;
        stop_volatile = true;
    });

    Thread thread1 = new Thread(() -> {
        while (true) {
            if (stop_volatile){
                System.out.println("thread1:" + stop);
                break;
            }
        }
    });

    Thread thread2 = new Thread(() -> {
        while (true) {
          if (stop){
              System.out.println("thread2:" + stop);
              break;
          }
        }
    });

    thread0.start();
    thread1.start();
    thread2.start();
}
```

There are two static fields, `stop` and `stop_volatile`, and `stop_volatile` is marked `volatile`. thread0 changes both to the true.
thread1 can stop and thread2 runs forever.

Why does thread1 print "thread1:true", why can it get right value from field `stop` in thread1 always, it is not a volatile field?

In Thread 0, after modifying the value of "stop_volatile," it writes its working cache to memory and notifies other threads that their working cache of the changed value is invalidated. Then, when other threads access this variable, they need to reload it from memory. Here, "stop" is a non-volatile variable. Why does Thread 1 not continue to use the cached value and instead reloads it as well?

Comment: `thread1` hasn't ever accessed `stop` before the `println`, so that'll be the first time it accesses it. Also: the lack of volatile doesn't guarantee any specific "caching" of variables. `volatile` simply forbids some kinds of optimizations, but those are not required without it.

Comment: What I mainly want to ask is why thread1 can got the right value of stop, but thread2 cannot.

Comment: I implied that but didn't spell it out: `thread1` has never seen the old value, so it's not "cached" (not quite the right word, but let's leave it like that) there and it'll try to read that value only once it's got the new value. `thread2` however, has seen the "old" value and never re-reads it from main memory again.

Comment: however,before the code "if (stop_volatile)",add line "if (stop) System.out.println(1);" but also no change

Answer (score 1):

The read of a volatile field will make the thread see all changes that occurred before the last write to that field (the so called *happens-before* relationship). So, given thread1 repeatedly reads the volatile `stop_volatile`, and the write to `stop` occurred *before* the write to `stop_volatile`, thread1 is guaranteed to see the changes to `stop` as well.

And as Joachim Sauer points out in the comments, this is the one and only time thread1 accesses `stop`, so there was nothing "cached" previously for that thread, while thread2 continuously accesses `stop`, so it is more likely to see a "cached" value (or it might even be optimized to `if (false)`!).

Though it is tough to read, you may want to read the [17.4 Memory Model](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4) section of the Java Language Specification, which details this.

What basically happens is that you have the following actions:

- in thread0: `stop = true` *happens-before* `stop_volatile = true`

  - `stop_volatile = true` is a *synchronization action*
- in thread1, `stop_volatile` is read

  - reading from `stop_volatile` is also a *synchronization action*
  - as result, the write to `stop_volatile` *happens-before* the read to `stop_volatile`

As specified in section 17.4.5 Happens-before Order:

> If we have two actions *x* and *y*, we write *hb(x, y)* to indicate that *x happens-before y*.
>
> - If *x* and *y* are actions of the same thread and *x* comes before *y* in program order, then *hb(x, y)*.
> - There is a *happens-before* edge from the end of a constructor of an object to the start of a finalizer (§12.6) for that object.
> - If an action *x synchronizes-with* a following action *y*, then we also have *hb(x, y)*.
> - If *hb(x, y)* and *hb(y, z)*, then *hb(x, z)*.

In other words (using *t0* and *t1* as shorthand for *thread0* and *thread1*), given:

- *hb(write to `stop` (t0), write to `stop_volatile` (t0))*, and
- *hb(write to `stop_volatile` (t0), read from `stop_volatile` (t1))*, also means
- *hb(write to `stop` (t0), read from `stop_volatile` (t1))*,

And so the subsequent read on thread1 will see the updated value of `stop`.

You can see this by working out the *happens-before* further: *hb(read from `stop_volatile` (t1), read from `stop` (t1))* implies *hb(write to `stop` (t0), read from `stop` (t1))*.